# elementFromPoint sometimes returns an element with pointer-events style set to none

Tags: javascript, mouseevent

From [developer.mozilla.org - `elementFromPoint(x, y)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint):

> The elementFromPoint() method, available on the Document object, returns the topmost Element at the specified coordinates (relative to the viewport).
>
> [...]
>
> Elements with **pointer-events set to none** will be ignored, and the element below it will be returned.

For the most part this is also my experience, however, in some cases I've noticed that the function actually does return an element where `element.style.pointerEvents` is `'none'`. Given the following piece of code, this causes an endless loop which freezes the page:

```js
function getFirstImageUnderPointer(ev) {
    const { clientX, clientY } = ev;
    const elementStylePairs = [];
    let hoveredElement = document.elementFromPoint(clientX, clientY);
    
    while (hoveredElement instanceof HTMLElement && hoveredElement.tagName !== "HTML" && hoveredElement.tagName !== "IMG") {
        elementStylePairs.push([hoveredElement, hoveredElement.style.pointerEvents]);
        hoveredElement.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
        hoveredElement = document.elementFromPoint(clientX, clientY);
    }
    
    // Set original style
    for (let pair of elementStylePairs) {
        pair[0].style.pointerEvents = pair[1];
    }
    
    return hoveredElement instanceof HTMLImageElement
        ? hoveredElement
        : null;
}

function handleMouseDown(ev) {
    const img = getFirstImageUnderPointer(ev);
    console.log(img?.id);
}

document.body.addEventListener("mousedown", handleMouseDown, { capture: true });
```

I've not been able to figure out exactly why this happens, but it seems to be reproducible on Twitter/X videos; if the above code is pasted directly into the developer console (I've tested in Firefox) from a Twitter/X page with a video on and you click the timeline/progress bar, then you'll get stuck in an endless loop. If you break on the first line in the loop, you'll see that `hoveredElement.style.pointerEvents === 'none'` before this code sets the value.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Guessing this is probably the same issue, as with things like trying to set a class dynamically, and then trying to read changed CSS values that would result from that class change, directly afterwards ... Meaning, the JS engine has probably not given back control to the rendering engine at this point, and it would probably need one of the usual workarounds (requestAnimationFrame, setTimeout, _reading_ of a layout-related property, ...) - if that can be integrated in whatever you are actually tying to achieve here.

Comment: @CBroe Sounds likely, although, wouldn't it consistently cause an endless loop then? My goal here is to simply react whenever the mouse pointer is hovering an image when clicked (and find that image). The behavior here is just a side effect because the listener is always active - I'm not really interested in the video.

Comment: Are Twitter videos/pages your actual use case here, or what is?

Comment: @CBroe It's a browser extension, so it's any image (currently just `<img>` tags but might evolve) on any website. Whenever the page is loaded the content script will add this event listener. I do have ways to work around this issue so the question is more about whether my expectation above is misplaced and therefore have the wrong approach.

Comment: I would assume it to work as advertised, until something explicitly proves otherwise. I can't tell if there really is a problem with how the method itself behaves here - or if you _introduced_ a problem, by messing with the pointer-events of elements _while_ you are trying to process this.